# NoMethodError in Stories#show

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have followed tutorial from Simply Rails 2, but I got NoMethodError

this is my story.rb model :

```
class Story < ApplicationRecord
    validates :name, :link, presence: true
    has_many :votes do 
        def latest
            find :all, :order => 'id DECS', :limit => 3
        end
    end
end
```

this is my show.html.haml view :

```
%h2
  %span#vote_score
  Score: #{@story.votes.size}
 = @story.name


#vote_form
  = form_for @story, method: "post", :url => story_votes_path(@story) do
    = submit_tag 'shove it'

%ul#vote_history
  - if @story.votes.empty?
    %em No shoves yet!
  - else
    = render :partial => 'votes/vote', :collection => @story.votes.latest

%p
  = link_to @story.link, @story.link
```

Full Error desciption :

```
undefined method `latest' for #<Vote::ActiveRecord_Associations_CollectionProxy:0x00007f4234aea9c0>
Did you mean?  last

Extracted source (around line #15):

%em No shoves yet!
  - else
    = render :partial => 'votes/vote', :collection => @story.votes.latest ##this is line 15

%p
  = link_to @story.link, @story.link

Rails.root: /home/kevin/shovell2
```

Can anyone help me to solve this ? Thank You.

Comment: Why are you trying to learn Rails 2? That book is from 2008 (if its the Patrick Lenz book we are talking about) and is totally irrelevant today. `find :all` was depreciated years and years ago. In any modern versions of rails you would call `order(id: :desc).limit(3)`.

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure you want to pass that block to `has_many`? I think what you want is declaring that `latest` method in the `Vote` model, maybe a scope

```
scope :latest, -> { order('id DESC').limit(3) }
```

or the same with a method

```
def self.latest
  order('id DESC').limit(3)
end
```

A note about the version of rails you're using: you are making your model subclassing `ApplicationRecord`, and that exists in the latest versions of rails (probably from rails 5 upward). On the other hand this method seems from a very old version of rails, probably 2 `find :all, :order => 'id DECS', :limit => 3`

Answer (score 0):

You need to add latest to your Vote model not to your Story model. And it can be like this instead of method.

```rb
class Vote < ApplicationRecord
  ...
  scope :latest, -> { order('id DESC').limit(3) }
  ...
end
```

Comment: I have followed your instruction but still the same